# C# Winforms: How to make Return press Send?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to keep the focus in the `textBox` but the Keyboard Return key presses the Send button?
[image]

Comment: Have you set your [ Send ] button as the accept button for the form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set the `AcceptButton` property of the `Form` to be your Send button, that should make the form respond to Enter by triggering the Send button.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Form.AcceptButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the forms `AcceptButton` property to the "Send" button's control name.

Answer (score 2):

Set form's [`AcceptButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx) to your send button